# Как найти все точки пересечения нуля с функцией и отобразить их на графике?

Tags: python, функции, matplotlib

Пытаюсь найти пересечения с нулем с помощью смены знака функции, т.к. не факт, что среди значений "x" функция будет равна 0. Однако точки расставляются некорректно из-за неправильного прохода по функции.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func():

    x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
    y = x*x - 10
    s = np.sign(y)
    zeroes = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if s[i-1] + s[i] == 0:
            zeroes.append(i)

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot([y[i] for i in zeroes],'ro')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

func()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG5L2.png
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вы странное пытаетесь рисовать, я исправил. Наверняка можно ещё проще сделать, но так понятно и работает. Ну то есть проблема у вас в отрисовке была, а не в вычислениях.

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot([x[i] for i in zeroes], [y[i] for i in zeroes],'ro')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: zeroes]